# Can't set Default State of Checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter

What I intended to get my program do was to set the initial state of checkbutton according to list `checkbox_states`, but it didn't work; the program only generates unchecked checkbuttons.

The part that generates checkbutton is in function `create_task_label`.

Before reading, I apologize about the code being not so good to read, and some awkward English - I'm new to python and Eng is not my first language

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import date


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("To-do-list Program")
window.configure(bg="#777777")

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

window_width = 600
window_height = 700

x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
y = (screen_height - window_height) // 2

window.resizable(False, False)

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")


left_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=600, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground='#ffffff')
left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(left_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

canvas = tk.Canvas(left_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=400, height=600)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

inner_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=inner_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

def scroll(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", scroll)


def save_tasks():
    with open(TASKS_FILE, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
            checkbox_state = "True" if checkbox_states[i] else "False"
            file.write(f"{task['content']},{task['date']},{checkbox_state}\n")

def load_tasks():
    try:
        with open(TASKS_FILE, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                content, date, checkbox_state = line.strip().split(",")
                task = {
                    "content": content,
                    "date": date
                }
                tasks.append(task)
                checkbox_states.append(checkbox_state == "True")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "File with info of To-do-list doesn't exist.")

def sort_tasks():
    tasks.sort(key=lambda x: x['date'])

def render_tasks():
    global inner_frame

    inner_frame.destroy()
    inner_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=inner_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

    sort_tasks() # 과제 목록 정렬

    for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
        create_task_label(task['content'], task['date'], i)

    canvas.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, inner_frame.winfo_height()))

def create_task_label(content, date, index):
    frame = tk.Frame(inner_frame, bd=10)
    frame.pack(anchor=tk.W)

    label_font = tkfont.Font(family="D2Coding", size=12)

    checkbox_state=tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbox_state.set(checkbox_states[index])
    value = checkbox_state.get()

    print(checkbox_states[index],' ',value)

    checkbox_labels.insert(index, label_font)
    labels.insert(index, tk.Label(frame, text=f"{content} [{date}]", font=label_font, disabledforeground='#000000', activeforeground='#777777', state='active' if checkbox_states[index] else 'disabled'))
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(frame, command=lambda: checkbox_changed(index), variable=checkbox_state)
    checkbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    labels[index].pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    delete_button = tk.Button(frame, text="삭제", command=lambda: delete_task(index))
    delete_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    remaining_days = get_remaining_days(date)
    if remaining_days >= 0:
        remaining_days_label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"{remaining_days}-day")
        if remaining_days <= 3:
            remaining_days_label.configure(fg="#ff7700")
    else:
        remaining_days_label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"{-remaining_days}+day", fg='#ff0000')
    remaining_days_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

TASKS_FILE = "tasks.txt"

tasks = []

checkbox_states = []
checkbox_labels = []
labels = []

load_tasks()
sort_tasks()

def checkbox_changed(index):
    checkbox_states[index] = not checkbox_states[index]

    if checkbox_states[index]:
        print(checkbox_states)
        checkbox_labels[index].configure(overstrike=True)
        labels[index].configure(state='active')
    else:
        print(checkbox_states)
        checkbox_labels[index].configure(overstrike=False)
        labels[index].configure(state='disabled')

inner_frame.update_idletasks()
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

render_tasks()

def on_closing():
    save_tasks()
    window.destroy()

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

window.mainloop()
```

I searched all about this on google and did everything that chatgpt recommended, but nothing worked

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to run your code but since I don't have the `task.txt` file I can't see what the loaded GUI is meant to look like. Could you please provide an example of this file for testing purposes ?

Comment: Create a minimal example that reproduces the problem - create a test list, place some Checkbuttons, give them default values.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `checkbox_state` is a local variable inside function `create_task_label()` and it will be garbage collected after exiting the function.  You need to save the reference, for example using an attribute of the checkbutton:

```py
def create_task_label(content, date, index):
    ...
    checkbox_state = tk.BooleanVar()
    ...
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(frame, command=lambda: checkbox_changed(index), variable=checkbox_state)
    checkbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    checkbox.variable = checkbox_state # use an attribute to save the reference of the tkinter variable
    ...
```